# How to get ascii from a hexdump using hd?

Tags: linux, ascii, hexdump

I have this hexdump:

```
0100 0000 3f00 0000 0a59 6f55 90df 0100
0f00 0000 6d6f 746f 726f 6c61 2058 5431
3036 3839 3744 3245 3430 3630 3737 4143
3531 3632 3930 3937 3244 3933 3845 4343
```

I believe it's one space-seperated, 8 columns, zero filled, 2 digits hex numbers.

I wanted to convert this hexdump back to ascii with the hexdump (hd) utility.

How to proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually this is not all the string I'm posting here so converting it by hand won't be an option. I'm having a text file having this string. Another tool? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: [Hexadecimal -> ASCII string decoder](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_ascii.php?lang=en) -> [1][0][0][0]?[0][0][0][10]YoU[144][223][1][0][15][0][0][0]motorola XT106897D2E406077AC516290972D938ECC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do in Linux:

```
$ echo '0100 0000 3f00 0000 0a59 6f55 90df 0100
0f00 0000 6d6f 746f 726f 6c61 2058 5431
3036 3839 3744 3245 3430 3630 3737 4143
3531 3632 3930 3937 3244 3933 3845 4343' | xxd -r -p
?
YoU��motorola XT106897D2E406077AC516290972D938ECC
```